# TypeError message uses name instead of qualname

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, qualified-name

I find the following behavior:

```
>>> def f():
...     def g(a,b):
...         return a+b
...     return g
>>> f().__name__
... 'g'
>>> f().__qualname__
... 'f.<locals>.g'
>>> f()(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: g() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

I would like the error message to show the `__qualname__` of the function involved instead of just the `__name__`. This is afaik also the recommended practice when writing such messages yourself.

Can I do anything about this (e.g. configuration on startup)?
Or is this a bug/feature?

Showing the qualname would make debugging a lot easier, especially when working with decorators or lambdas.

---

python 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

This isn't configurable; it's hard coded in the interpreter internals. If you feel strongly about it, [file a bug with the CPython folks](https://bugs.python.org/). Given that `__qualname__` is a newer feature, they may not have considered or gotten around to using it in this context.

**Update:** Looks like there is [a bug already filed](https://bugs.python.org/issue2786), but it hasn't seen any activity in the last couple years.